# Rails Method Ignoring Default Param - WHY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, parameter-passing

I am at a loss as to why this is happening.  I have the following function:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  json = {
    :id => id,
    # ... more unimportant code
    }
  unless options[:simple]
    # ... more unimportant code
  end
  json  
end
```

It works most of the time, but in one particular partial where I call this:

```
window.JSONdata = <%= @day.to_json.html_safe %>
```

I get the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):

Pointing to the line "unless options[:simple]".  As far as I can tell, the options hash is nil - thus the method is ignoring the default param assignment.  WHY?  I can fix this by changing the method to:

```
def as_json(options)
  options ||= {}
  json = {
    :id => id,
    # ... more unimportant code
    }
  unless options[:simple]
    # ... more unimportant code
  end
  json  
end
```

Does this make any sense to anyone!?  Most appreciative for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using `to_json`, which has a default `options` of `nil`. `to_json` will eventually call `as_json` and pass the `nil` as `options`.

Here's where it happens on the Rails source code. First, `to_json` is defined with the default `options` of `nil`.

```
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.7/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb#L15
def to_json(options = nil)
  ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self, options)
end
```

Eventually it will arrive here.

```
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.7/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L41
def encode(value, use_options = true)
  check_for_circular_references(value) do
    jsonified = use_options ? value.as_json(options_for(value)) : value.as_json
    jsonified.encode_json(self)
  end
end
```

As you see, `as_json` is called with `value.as_json(options_for(value))` and `options_for(value)` will return the default value of `to_json`, which is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great response - it was really clear and informative!

Comment: One last question.  I tried calling to_json using the console before I posted this question to see if the issue was with that function.  However in the console, both to_json and as_json worked fine.  Any idea why the console didn't generate the error?

Comment: It behaves as expected on console for me. Maybe you didn't reload or restart the console to reflect the code at that moment.

Comment: Your probably right about reload.  Thanks again for the help!